# Error when loading a php module

Tags: php, unix, ubuntu, curl, nginx

I added the curl module in /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini :

```
extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/curl.so
```

but when I restart php and I do :

```
php -m
```

I get this error :

```
curl : Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP    compiled with module API=20141010
These options need to match
```

---

I also tried :

```
apt-get install php5-curl
```

Curl is "already to the new version".

---

And phpinfo() tells php5 is running :

```
PHP Version 5.5.9
php.ini Path :  /etc/php5/fpm 
PHP Extension : 20121212
```

but when I check on the server with :

```
which php  => /usr/bin/php  (for php7)
php -v     => PHP 7.0  (with a warning before "Unable to initialize module")
```

---

and if I remove curl.so in the php.ini above (the one of php7, at 1st line) the warning disapear.

### ---------------------------------------

so I added : extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/curl.so

in :

```
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

then I restart, but I still can't see this module :

[image]

And here the error saying this module is still missing :

[image]

Comment: Well, you have to install curl the same way you installed PHP (you don't really say). Are you 100% sure that php5-curl contains curl for PHP **7**?

Comment: thank you for your answer but I also tried "apt-get install curl" and exactly the same, also installed, is there a specific curl package for php7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you're trying to add the module to webserver's PHP, which is in your case PHP5, you need to add that module to `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` (based on your previous question where you stated that you use NGINX+PHP-FPM).

If you want to add it to the CLI version - you're doing it wrong, cause you're adding PHP5 module to PHP7 - that won't work, you need to install `php7-curl` and it will auto-add itself where needed.

---

To elaborate somewhat more. Your `phpinfo()` tells you that your INI path is in `/etc/php5/fpm`:

```
PHP Version 5.5.9 
php.ini Path :  /etc/php5/fpm  
PHP Extension : 20121212
```

Hence, to add any extensions to *that* particular PHP - just add them to `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`. Note, you can not (or very rarely) add extensions from one version of PHP to another version of PHP.

---

I'll add a summary of what's happening on the OP's system for future reference then.

Basically, OP has 2 versions of PHP installed on the system simultaneously, PHP5 and PHP7 with an NGINX werserver with `php-fpm` extension.

His NGINX is configured to use PHP5, while CLI PHP defaults to PHP7.

The confusion with OP comes from the fact that on an Ubuntu system there's a clear difference between the PHP that's called from the CLI and the PHP that's used by webserver.

CLI tools are available per-version as `/usr/bin/php5` and `/usr/bin/php7`, with one default link `/usr/bin/php` pointing to one particular version, in this case PHP7.

For the FPM module, there are 2 packages available `php5-fpm` and `php7-fpm`, with respective configs in `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.0/php.ini`.

For the CLI, there are 2 packages available as well - `php5-cli` and `php7-cli`, with respective configs in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`.

For curl extension, there's the same story, `php5-curl` and `php7-curl`. Extensions will be auto-wired to the needed INI files by the deb installer.

Installing multiple versions of PHP for fun can create this kind of confusion. :)

Comment: thank you very much again, I tried and I updated the question with what you said, I think we approach to the solution but I can't see yet this module..

Comment: Heh, again, cli PHP is different from fpm. What do you mean you "restart php"? How do you do it?

Comment: service php5-fpm restart

Comment: If you want to have that module in _both_ cli PHP and FPM PHP, you also need to add it in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and then check with `/usr/bin/php5 -m`

Comment: so I added it also in ../cli/php.ini and  when I check with /usr/bin/php5 -m, I can see this module, but it's like this module is still missing, I posted a printscreen in the question with this error

Comment: Run it as `php5 composer.phar update`, rather than `php`, since your system defaults to PHP7.

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST!!!!! it works with what you said, big big thank you favoretti!!!

Comment: big thank you again for your time, big big thank you, I feel much better now:)

Comment: @Julien I added somewhat more elaborate summary of what's happening on your system - maybe that will clear some things up somewhat more?

Comment: yes thank you a lot, that helps to understand better

Comment: For the answer I just deleted, a couple thoughts to consider: ...nstead of downvoting and costing the poster points, you could have edited the answer to say the problem w/it, or commented and waited for them to delete it. Meanwhile, it may not help this person, but may help someone else who clicks on it. And wasn't not obvious to me that he's running his own server. He may be co-running w/something else. Such as when I was at IBM, I was heavily dependent on other setups even though creating my own. However, after I post this I will delete that answer so that it doesn't disturb anyone else.

Comment: From the badge for downvoting: The up-vote privilege comes first because that's what you should focus on: pushing great content to the top. Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing. ///// Instead of voting down: If the post is spammy or offensive, flag it. If the question is duplicate or off-topic, flag it for moderator attention. If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it.

Comment: @curls if you haven't noticed your answer's rating remained at 0. that's why we both commented, rather than downvoted :)

Comment: Oh, very nice.  Thank you.  The comments said you were downvoting.  So question - should I undelete the answer or leave it deleted?  Not useful to this OP, but might add if a lost soul comes by who doesn't think about the hosting company's setup.  So I'm torn.  Actually something downvoted big time somewhere because I got 125 points badge and am now down at 115.  I never saw the 125 but the badge notice is there, but not working.  That's why I assumed it came from here.

Comment: undelete it, even if it was not the right answer, the comment of @favoretti was interesting to explain why it was not that (and don't be stick to your pts, just practice and learn:)

Comment: Thanks @Julien.  Done.

Comment: @favoretti glad to read that you work at eBay, I'm also working for a classified site, when I'll be rich I'll hire you and you'll be my technical director!!;)

Comment: @curls and OP: you guys both know that comments to the questions aren't meant to be the chat site? :P

Comment: yes we'll be banned by moderator and @curls will lose all his pts :P

Answer (score 0):

That means that your CURL module was compiled against a different version of PHP. Depending on your flavor of Linux (looks like Debian flavor) you might need to install a module

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Comment: thank you but I tried this million times and it's "already to the newest version"

Comment: Ok, then what version of php-5-curl is installed?

Comment: curl version is 7.35.0 from phpinfo()

Comment: Sorry, I mean the php5-curl package. What version is it? The version of CURL itself is irrelevant

Comment: ah ok sorry, and how can I check that? I also updated the question with a few things strange

Comment: `apt-cache show php5-curl` Also a good idea to show `apt-cache show php5`

Comment: I don't find where is the version of php5-curl but I see : "source php5, version 5.5.9"

Answer (score 0):

What about calling your hosting company to see what versions they have available and which one's your code are picking up?

Maybe they have some unique setup that's picking versions in a way you aren't picturing (one wouldn't picture.)

Comment: Don't wanna downvote, but this answer is totally misleading. The OP is obviously running his own server, it has nothing to do with hosting company.

Comment: same for me, didn't want to downvote but I was also surprised by this answer