# different result between php -v and phpinfo()

Tags: unix, ubuntu, php

I don't understand at all why :

```
php -v
(or) php -m
```

return : PHP 7.0

and phpinfo() says I am using PHP 5.

it's strange, any idea?

---

I'm using Ubuntu and Nginx. Below is a printscreen :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post prinscreens? Are you sure they're the same installation? What OS are you using? Are there any webservers? Which one(s)?

Comment: phpinfo() from a webserver?

Comment: From the command line do a `which php` and see if the php that is running there is a different binary than the one the web is using.

Comment: @AlanMachado I added printscreens, it's really strange

Comment: @DigitalChris which php gives also php7

Comment: `which php` should return the full path to the php executable. Compare this to the php executable that is referenced in phpinfo to see if they are in different paths.

Comment: @DigitalChris note that `cli` version of PHP has nothing to do with the FPM module his nginx is loading, so comparing paths of the CLI tool won't give you anything in particular, other than confirmation that both versions are installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not strange. `php -v` runs `php-cli`, which in turn reads a different ini file. `phpinfo()` is evaluated by your webserver, which reads a webserver-specific ini file.

In case of Ubuntu, those are: `/etc/phpX/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/phpX/cli/php.ini`, for nginx in your case it uses `php-fpm`, whose config is located in `/etc/phpX/fpm/php.ini`.

---

Also, in your case PHP7 is probably either compiled or pulled from some other repo. If you want nginx to pick up PHP7, you'll need to either compile or install `php7-fpm` or something in those lines. YMMV depending on how you got PHP7 onto your system.

---

To get a feeling of how this works - create a file anywhere on the filesystem inside your web folder, say, called `test.php` with the following content:

```
<?

phpinfo();

?>
```

Then try running:

```
# php test.php
```

and then access this file from a web browser at http://path.to.your.site.com/path/to/test.php

You'll see that cli PHP will report version 7.0, whereas nginx will keep reporting PHP5.

Comment: would using a different `php.ini` file  report a different php version?

Comment: @RyanVincent yes, if your system has both versions installed and nginx is configured to load the fpm module from php5 (which judging from his `phpinfo()` output is the case)

Comment: @favoretti thank you and I think php7 came after an apt-get upgrade, so today I'm using php5 right? even if I see the php7 directory?

Comment: @Julien if you're certain it came from `apt-get upgrade`, the only thing you miss is `apt-get install php7-fpm` I think and then updating nginx configuration. That is if you really need PHP7. If not - I think your PHP5 CLI binary should still be under `/usr/bin/php5`, so if you run `/usr/bin/php5 -v`, you'll find your PHP5 CLI back :)

Comment: @favoretti and if you don't mind, I've a problem when I try to load a module, I'll be very happy if you can also help me for that, I opened another question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106583/error-when-loading-a-php-module

Answer (score 2):

You need to change default php version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

Comment: This is exactly it. I had php8.0 in `phpinfo()` but 7.3 in the `(cli)` this helped me match them both to 8.0

Answer (score 1):

If your system is like this:

- `ubuntu`
- `NGNIX`
- `php-fpm`

So you should to change your `ngnix` config:

in `/etc/ngnix/sites-available` nano per your address and change the `fpm` version:

```
  location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
```

then restart your ngnix

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
```

now check your php version with `phpinfo()` and `php -v` on cli.

Comment: This is great, along with the other answers. I always forget these config. files

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem while upgrading from PHP5 to PHP7 on Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache, here's what helped me (credit goes [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/php-v-is-7-0-11-and-phpinfo-is-5-5-9)):

Disable PHP5 module on Apache:

```
sudo a2dismod php5
```

Now enable PHP7:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.1
```

To reflect changes Apache restart is required:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: The question is specifically about nginx, not Apache.